# Formatting urls in yii1

Tags: yii

I have a url `http://test.site.loc/profile/membership/view/id/1`> I do not know how to format it in such a way that if I type http://test.site.loc/profile/membership/view/1, it will direct the same url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your URL in 'URL Manager' like

```
'/profile/membership/view/<id>' => '/profile/membership/view'
```

which will route you to 'view' action and you can get 'id' with following code

```
Yii::app()->request->getParam('id');
```

and create your URL as follows

```
echo CHtml::link("Label",
     Yii::app()->createUrl(
             '/profile/membership/view', 
             array(
                 'id'=>1 
             )
     )
);
```

Comment: For more information http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#parameterizing-routes