# How to impliment links in yii 1?

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code:

```
    return array(
        ULogt::UPDATE => '

 <div>     
    <a href="#link">Navigate</a>
 </div>
'
```

This code locates in the class called links.php.
I need to navigate to `('viewform', array('model'=>$this->loadJson($id))`, when the user presses Navigate button. I do not know how to insert this code instead of `#link`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
CHtml::link( 
   "Navigate", 
   "javascript:void(0);", // link for destination or you can handle same with jQuery
   array(
    'id' => 'navigation-id', // id for handeling in jQuery
    'key' => $data, // Required data will be appeared as attributes for this link
   )
);
```

You can create link like

```
Yii::app()->createUrl(
         '/profile/membership/view', // your link
         array(
             'id'=> 1  // data to be sent
         )
 )
```

[Check for URL formating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172588/formating-urls-in-yii1)